# Exponent value in long tail phenomenon of online store

Tags: zipf, heavy-tailed

I've read ([pdf](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/book.pdf)) that there is a long-tail phenomenon (or generalized Zipf law) in popularity of retail items: If I sort items for sale by their popularity, I will see a long tail of not very popular items. This is used as an argument as to why online retailers (amazon), have an advantage over store retailers, as they can keep inventory of even the most unpopular items.

Does anyone know what is the typical behaviour of the long tail in the real world? E.g. does it look like $ popularity \sim 1/order^\alpha $, or does it drop faster/slower than a power law? This is important to substantiate the argument that online retail has advantage. For example, if $ \alpha = 1$, then it seems I will get the same amount of sales by holding the first 1,000 most popular items, as I will get by holding the items with popularity order between 1,001 and 1,000,000 (since $\int_a^b(1/x)dx = \ln(b/a)$). In this case, I would find it hard to see the advantage (as the cost of holding 1,000 times more items will be overwhelming).

Comment: See for instance https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=918142